# Prove that there is no homomorphism $f:\mathbb { Z } / n \mathbb { Z }\rightarrow \mathbb { Z }$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

> **Problem** Prove that there is no homomorphism $f:\mathbb { Z } / n \mathbb { Z } \rightarrow \mathbb { Z }$

**My attempt:** By contradiction, let's suppose that there exists as such. We then have $0 = f(0) = f(n \cdot \overline { 1 })=n\cdot f(\overline { 1 })= n$. Absurd.

What do you think of my solution?

Comment: Guessing from your user name, I assume you mean homomorphism *of (unital) rings*. Which you should always add if it's not absolutely clear from context. As otherwise, I would ask you here: How do you know that $f(\overline{1})=1$?

Comment: This is correct. Depending on the audience you might need to specify that $n \cdot x$ means $x + x + \ldots + x$ where the total number of $x$'s in the expression is $x$, but frankly I guess that for most readers that is obvious.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg $f ( \overline { 1 } ) = 1 ?$ by definition of homomorphism.What do you mean by my username?

Comment: Ha! I was assuming a homomorphism of *abelian groups* (hence the need to clarify the 'external' $\mathbb{Z}$ action) so this difference in interpretation between Torsten and me underlines Torsten's point that it should be made clear what the objects are

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг could you explain why the zero homomorphism is a homomorphism? From wikipedia (and also my course) a homomorphism needs $f \left( 1 _ { R } \right) = 1 _ { S }$, i.e *unity (multiplicative identity) is preserved$. But how is true for the zero homomorphism?

Comment: Oh! In that case your working is fine : your question did require more context, as shown in the comments, however with the context now clarified it is clear to see you've ticked all the right boxes.

Comment: Should also add : since there's nothing more to say really, please add an answer yourself, accept it(or some other answer if it has come) and close the question.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Alright thank you very much :)

Comment: +1,You are welcome!  Speaking of which there's an answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A ring homomorphism  $f:\mathbb { Z } / n \mathbb { Z }\rightarrow \mathbb { Z }$ induces a homomorphism of additive groups $\mathbb { Z } / n \mathbb { Z }\rightarrow \mathbb { Z }$.
A slight generalization of your argument proves that this group homomorphism is the zero homomorphism and so $f$ is the zero map. Whether the zero map qualifies as a ring homomorphism depends on your definitions.